# How to identify JSR version supported by a Portal?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6, jsr

Given a particular Portal and the portlet running in it, how to identify the JSR version that it supports?

More specifically, I want to know if Liferay CE 6.0 supports only JSR 168? And the support for JSF 286 was provided only after 6.1?

I have some portlets running on Liferay CE 6.0 which have below piece of information in `portlet.xml`.

`<portlet-app version="2.0"..`

Does version 2.0 indicate that it adheres to JSR 286 and whereas version 1.0 indicates that it adheres to JSF 168?

Comment: Yes... Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. So, you mean to say, Liferay 6.0 CE supports JSR 286? Do you have any link which gives list of Liferay versions and corresponding JSR versions?

Comment: Liferay supports JSR 286 since version 5

Comment: @Sandeep: Why not state this as an answer?

Comment: @Olaf, I thought it's just a one liner, hence did not add it. Let me add it.

Comment: This way it can get accepted and voted up. Sometimes the simple factual information is just what the next visitors to this questions are looking for. @user2488578 please accept Sandeep's answer, he's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes version 2.0 means it adheres to JSR 286. Please check [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification).

Liferay supports JSR 286 since version 5.